# I can't solve two matrix multiple in pulp objective

Tags: matrix, optimization, logarithm, pulp

I am a novice in writing code in programing.
I'm having trouble writing a objective code in the Python pulp library and I can't solve its error.
I write to python code a logarithm expression that is a multiple of two matrices.
The form of my problem and my code are as follows.
please help me.

[image]

```
from pulp import *

m = LpVariable('m', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
n = LpVariable('n', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# --------------------------------------- decision variable

x = LpVariable.matrix("x",(range(m),range(n)),0,1,cat = 'Binary')
P = LpVariable.matrix("P",(range(m),range(n)),cat = 'Integer')
G = LpVariable.matrix("G",(range(m),range(n)),cat = 'Integer')
model = pulp.lpDot(P, G)
print(model, type(model))
```

Comment: PuLP is **only** for linear programming. Even minimal reading of documentation should make that totally clear. Ignoring that, you try to force-feed it a nonlinear objective and constraint. Obviously, that is not so easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guide me. What library do you think I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: This is an MINLP model so you should use an MINLP solver. Or use a linear reformulation.